# UIWebView doesn't trigger delegates if I change the page of index.html page (monocle)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Can someone tell me how I can get to know which page I am viewing in `UIWebView` which I am loading with an HMTL file `index.html` (monocle)?

The `UIWebView` delegate are triggered only when I swipe and view the first page and when I swipe and view the last page.

Please suggest me a method to resolve this.